# Enabling FTP Port in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

We have new a server running HyperV with an SBS and SQL server.

Using our old server we used to run a small application which would connect to various external FTP hosts and download backups of websites.

If I run this application on our new server it seems it cannot access any of the sites, which makes me think it is being blocked.

So, how do I enable the ports (20 & 21 I think?) and can I enable them in such a way as to only allow this one application to connect and download data?

I don't want to allow FTP access to our server itself.

Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the Windows Firewall, should that be the Firewall of choice you have. You can allow an application only for outgoing connections and block incoming ones (Which, in many cases, is the default for Personal Computers). You shouldn't need to specify any ports for your FTP process. Just find out what application you are using for FTP and allow it outgoing, maybe for certain IP ranges, ... if you really want to.

Comment: Well we have a CISCO firewall as well but it's the same one we had on our old server so I expect it isn't blocking FTP

Comment: Are you talking about a Software Firewall installed locally as Softare on your Server or a Hardware-Firewall for the entire company? You need FTP outgoing to be enabled on both, if you have them. Having a local Software Firewall (packet filter) might not be too wrong for internal issues.

Comment: I've just allowed the application through Windows Firewall and it works perfectly, didn't realise it would be that straightforward. Thanks!